# C++ 2D array grid and pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, grid, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array acting as a grid for a game board:

```
shared_ptr<Tile> grid[20][10] // 20x10 grid
```

And I would like to initialize each Tile in the grid with neighbours in the constructor:

```
/* Generate 20x10 (connected) tiles */
for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        grid[x][y] = shared_ptr<Tile>(new Tile(x, y, room));
    }
}
```

And in `Tile`:

```
Tile::Tile(int x, int y, shared_ptr<Tile> grid[][10]) {
    /* Connected rooms */
    shared_ptr<Tile> north;
    shared_ptr<Tile> south;
    shared_ptr<Tile> east;
    shared_ptr<Tile> west;

    /* North */
    if (y > 0) {
        north = shared_ptr<Tile>(grid[x][y - 1]);
    }

    /* South */
    if (y < Y_TILES - 1) {
        south = shared_ptr<Tile>(grid[x][y + 1]);
    }

    /* East */
    if (x > 0) {
        east = shared_ptr<Tile>(grid[x - 1][y]);
    }

    /* West */
    if (x < X_TILES - 1) {
        west = shared_ptr<Tile>(grid[x + 1][y]);
    }
    ....
};
```

But as you expect, when I generate the 20x10 tiles, they only have connections to tiles that have already been generated!

For example, I generate `[1][1]` and it **should** have a `south` and `east` connection, but it doesn't. When I generate `[2][1]`, it does indeed have a `west` connection, but no `south` or `east`. This is due to the tiles not existing at the time of creation of those tiles..

I was thinking of using pointers so when the tile is generated, it will still be pointed to (and if not, it will simply be `NULL`), but these pointers are doing my head in.

Anyone see any obvious flaws from the above code that is causing the issue? Seems like I'm missing something important relating to pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you need to set a Tile's neighbours in the constructor? Why not just add a `setNeighbour()` function?

Comment: The problem is that you are copying the `shared_ptr`s why don't you keep their addresses instead like `shared_ptr<Tile> *north;` and update them like this `north = &(shared_ptr<Tile>(grid[x][y - 1]));`

Comment: Lots of other questions too - is there a reason that they need to be shared pointers? Do you have to do whatever it is you're doing in the constructor? How about you construct them all, and then call a method on each to set them up once they've all been constructed?

Comment: No reason for shared pointers, just for easier garbage collection. I didn't add a `setNeighbhour()` function as I thought this way would be more elegant. Anywho, I went for the `setNeighbhour()` path, and all is well now. Thanks for your help guys.